# Consultar mes anterior a la fecha actual

Tags: oracle

muy buenas noches, necesito resolver una duda super cortita, me gustaría saber como quitar un mes a la fecha actual, resulta que tengo que hacer una consulta la cual me tiene que devolver los valores del mes anterior al cual estoy consultando en este caso seria octubre y esta debe estar dentro del where, al hacer la consulta me arroja un error.
espero me puedan ayudar.
saludos

Comment: No estoy seguro de entender la pregunta. ¿Podrías añadir el código que te da el error para ver si así entiendo que pasa?

Answer (score 1):

En Oracle tienes la función para sumar o restar meses `ADD_MONTHS`.

En tu caso deberías poner esta función en el WHERE. Dependerá de tu tabla, de tus requerimiento exactos, etc., pero debería ser algo así

```
SELECT *
FROM TuTabla
WHERE CampoFecha = ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1)
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias estimado.